# How to perform conditional updates on shared variables in Theano?

Tags: python, theano

Is there a way to conditionally update the shared variables depending on the  result of the current function.
Eg.

```
g_W = T.grad(cost=classifier.cost,wrt=classifier.W)
updates=[(W,W-learning_rate*g_W)]
model = theano.function([index],outputs=cost,updates=updates)
```

In this model, I need to update the weight parameter only if the cost is greater than 0. There is a no_default_updates parameter in the function but it doesn't apply to 'updates' parameter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a symbolic conditional operation. Theano has two: `switch` and `ifelse`. `switch` is performed element-wise while `ifelse` works more like a conventional conditional. See the [documentation](http://deeplearning.net/software/theano/tutorial/conditions.html) for more.

Here's an example that updates parameters only when the cost is positive.

```
import numpy
import theano
import theano.tensor as tt


def compile(input_size, hidden_size, output_size, learning_rate):
    w_h = theano.shared(numpy.random.standard_normal((input_size, hidden_size))
                        .astype(theano.config.floatX), name='w_h')
    b_h = theano.shared(numpy.random.standard_normal((hidden_size,))
                        .astype(theano.config.floatX), name='b_h')
    w_y = theano.shared(numpy.random.standard_normal((hidden_size, output_size))
                        .astype(theano.config.floatX), name='w_y')
    b_y = theano.shared(numpy.random.standard_normal((output_size,))
                        .astype(theano.config.floatX), name='b_y')
    x = tt.matrix()
    z = tt.vector()
    h = tt.tanh(theano.dot(x, w_h) + b_h)
    y = theano.dot(h, w_y) + b_y
    c = tt.sum(y - z)
    updates = [(p, p - tt.switch(tt.gt(c, 0), learning_rate * tt.grad(cost=c, wrt=p), 0))
               for p in (w_h, b_h, w_y, b_y)]
    return theano.function([x, z], outputs=c, updates=updates)


def main():
    f = compile(input_size=3, hidden_size=2, output_size=4, learning_rate=0.01)


main()
```

In this case either `switch` or `ifelse` could be used but `switch` is generally preferable in such cases because `ifelse` does not appear to be as well supported throughout the Theano framework and requires a special import.

Comment: Thanks for the answer :). Really helpful